# Wildfly Server Multiple Domains?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 21.0.1.Final. I have deployed two WAR files from management console and I'm trying to get domain1.com to point to war1 and domain2.com to point to war2. Under the configuration below  it appears to point to the same WAR file (domain1 points to war1 and domain2 also points to war1). What am I doing wrong?

I've added the virtual host in my configuration:

```
<server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
                <host name="vhcertify" alias="www.domain2.com,domain2.com" default-web- 
                    module="domain2.war">
                    <http-invoker/>
                </host>
            </server>
```

Here is my jboss-web.xml file for WAR1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

and the jboss-web.xml file for WAR2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/</context-root>
   <virtual-host>vhcertify</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```